# Question with incrementing values in C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I am currently trying to get a number that increases by one each time its run, I am using a while loop, so in theory every time the loop is run in the code below, the int i should return 1,2,3,4 etc. Although instead it returns 1,1,1,1,1. Just can't get my head around this one.

```
public static void getresponse(ref int i)
{
    i++;
    System.Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

Comment: lots of answers below, but using a debugger and tracing the code helps diagnose these types of issues, you'll see exactly what each variable is asigned to.

Answer (score 3):

You're redeclaring i and setting it to 0 each time the loop runs.

Move `int i = 0` outside of the while loop.

```
    int i = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        getresponse(ref i);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare i outside your while loop.  It is being set to 0 each time.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        getresponse(ref i);
    }
}

public static void getresponse(ref int i)
{
  i++;
  System.Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

do you notice you reset i to 0 at every iteration?

just declare i outside the while block and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Put your counter outside of the loop.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        getresponse(ref i);
    }
}

public static void getresponse(ref int i)
{
   i++;
   System.Console.WriteLine(i);

}
```